# How to use the following piece of rsync command in subprocess call?

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a rsync command like this:

```
rsync --recursive source | grep "\."
```

I want to call this in subprocess like this:

```
subprocess.Popen(['sshpass', '-p', password, 'rsync', '--recursive', source, '|', 'grep', '"\."'],
                               stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

But it won't work. What's the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to invoke the shell with `shell=True`.  However, the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/subprocess.html) discourages using `shell=True`.

In order to avoid using `shell=True`, you can first create `rsync` process and pipe it's output to `grep`:

```
rsync_out = subprocess.Popen(['sshpass', '-p', password, 'rsync', '--recursive', source], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = subprocess.check_output(('grep', '\.'), stdin=rsync_out.stdout)
```